How to apply different filters on different routes (ContractRoute) in Http4k kotlin?
We have exposed some routes in our system (Example given in the code block below). We have a requirement where we want to expose some routes with AuthorisationFilter applied and some routes WITHOUT the AuthorisationFilter.
Question - How do we achieve something like this in Http4k. Couldn't find any examples in the Http4k Docs. Have tried the following but it did not work.
private val contract = contract {

    val apiDescription = "Some description for API"
    renderer = OpenApi3(
        ApiInfo(
            title = "Title",
            version = "v1.0.0",
            description = apiDescription
        ),
        CustomJackson
    )
    descriptionPath = "/docs/swaggerV2.json"
    routes += pingRoute()
    routes += getCustomerRoute()
}


private val filtersWithoutAuth = ResetMDCFilter()
    .then(EnvironmentMDCFilter(environment))
    .then(RequestLogFilter())
    .then(ResponseLogFilter())
    .then(CorrelationIdMDCFilter())
    .then(ErrorCodeCatchAllFilter(logger))
    .then(ErrorCodeLensFailureFilter(logger))

private val filtersWithAuth = AuthorisationFilter(jwtVerifier).then(filtersWithoutAuth)

val routes: HttpHandler = "/account" bind contract

private fun pingRoute(): ContractRoute {
    return "/ping" meta {
        summary = "ping"
        description = "Ping Api"
        returning(Status.OK to "The result")
    } bindContract Method.GET to filtersWithoutAuth.then { _ -> Response(Status.OK).body("pong")}
}

private fun getCustomerRoute(): ContractRoute {
    return "/customer" / Path.string().map(::CustomerNumber).of("customerNumber") meta {
        summary = "Gets customer account information"
        description = "Gets customer account information"
        returning(
            status = Status.OK,
            body = CustomerAccountDataResponse.bodyLens to CustomerAccountDataResponse()
        )
    } bindContract Method.GET to filtersWithAuth.then(accountEndpoints::getCustomerAccount)
}


if you are just worried about auth, then you can use the security option on the contract or the individual routes. There are also ways to set the filter stack to come before or after security so you may have to split your Filter stack.
"/api" bind contract {
      renderer = OpenApi3(ApiInfo("Storage Explorer (${T::class.java.simpleName})", "1.0"))
       security = ApiKeySecurity(Header.required("api_key"), { true })
       routes += listOf()
       preSecurityFilter = Filter.NoOp
       postSecurityFilter = Filter.NoOp
}

To override that security in a route we can do:
    "storage" / Path.of("key") meta {
        receiving(bodyLens)
        security = NoSecurity <-- this will override the default ApiKeySecurity
        returning(CREATED, ACCEPTED)
    } bindContract POST

Note that there are a small set of security types supported by the OpenAPI UI - so if you want to use the UI then you are limited to them. But overall Security is just a wrapper for a standard filter.
